# How can I extract only some specific folders from a tar.gz archive?

Tags: bash, tar

Let's say I have the archive `website.tar.gz`, inside is the following folder structure :

```
home  
  -mike 
    -www
      -coolwebsite
        file1
        file2
        file3
        etc.
```

When I extract the achive, it recreates exactly the same folder hierarchy (of course). I was hoping there was a way to extract for example only the "coolwebsite" folder to whichever folder I'm in at the moment.

So if I'm on my server in `mydir/` and I extract `website.tar.gz`, I want the result to be the `coolwebsite` folder, without all the preceding folders. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try this:

> `tar xvf` *tarfile* `--strip=4 ./home/mike/www/coolwebsite/*`

should remove to 4 levels of directories (including ".")

EDIT: add option z (i.e. tar xzvf ...) if the input file is *gzip*'ed

Comment: This command didn't work for me with GNU tar 1.23 (Error: `tar: ./Symfony/*: Not found in archive`. It did work when I removed the `./` part from the path however. And yes, I can confirm that the top level directory inside the archive was named Symfony. Additionally I had to append the `--wildcards` option. Maybe this answer needs an update?

Comment: It did not work for me. However, with **GNU tar**, the following switch worked for me: `--strip-components=4`.