# Extract specific folder from a tar.gz

Tags: unix, zip, tar

I know this question was previously asked on this site before like here [1](https://superuser.com/questions/155838/how-to-extract-a-single-folder-and-its-subfolders-from-a-tarball-tar-gz) and here [2](https://superuser.com/questions/344950/how-can-i-extract-only-some-specific-folders-from-a-tar-gz-archive) but no success for me.

I want to extract the `Measures` folder from my S012011_csv.tar.gz zipped file. If I do `tar -ztvf file.tar.gz` to see the content, you can see the folder directory structure:

`global//scratch//chamar//data//S012011_csv/Measures/file1.csv`

`global//scratch//chamar//data//S012011_csv/Measures/file2.csv`

and so on (yes there are `//`).

I only want to extract the subfolder `Measures` under folder `S012011_csv` in the current directory of the `.tar.gz` folder.

I have tried all these options but no success:

```
tar -xvzf S012011-v41_csv.tar.gz --strip=6 ./global//scratch//chamar//book//S012011-v41_csv/Mearsures/*

tar -xvzf S012011-v41_csv.tar.gz --strip=6 global//scratch//chamar//book//S012011-v41_csv/Mearsures/*

tar -xvzf S012011-v41_csv.tar.gz --strip=6 global/scratch/chamar/book/S012011-v41_csv/Mearsures/*

tar -xvzf S012011-v41_csv.tar.gz global/scratch/chamar/book/S012011-v41_csv/Mearsures/*
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tar -xvzf S012011-v41_csv.tar.gz "*S012011-v41_csv*Mearsures*"
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything. If I keep the `-v` option it only prints on screen the content of my folder `Measures`. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Try adding the --strip-path argument for removing all directories before and after the files you want to extract. I think the double slash could have something to do with this.

Comment: nope... I get this: `*S012011-v41_csv*Mearsures*: Not found in archive
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors`

Comment: I think you are right... the `//` is the problem... how can I bypass this?

Comment: I don't know. My bet was trying to make tar not use the double slashes in the output file name. But seems not to be working.

Comment: I will have to re-zip everything with no `//` (that was due to python)

Comment: I see. I have never come across such a problem before. Your file was corrupted at tar's eyes.